# fb-contrib bugs appears as unknown bug patterns

Tags: maven, findbugs

I am using **FindBugs** with maven, using the following configuration:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.mebigfatguy.fb-contrib</groupId>
                        <artifactId>fb-contrib</artifactId>
                        <version>6.2.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I run:

- `mvn clean`
- `mvn package`
- `mvn site`
- `mvn findbugs:gui`

And I get all errors listed in GUI, but I realized that all bugs detected by `fb-contrib` plugin are shown under `Experimental\Testing prototype and incomplete bug pattern\Unknown bug pattern` and **FindBugs** doesn't show any info about bug pattern.

Is this correct? Is it possible to get bug pattern info as with the **FindBugs** pattern bugs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it certainly shouldn't do that. It certainly doesn't if you run the findbugs gui from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

findbugs-maven-plugin doesn't supply the configured plugins, when it launches the FindBugs GUI ([Issue #37](https://github.com/gleclaire/findbugs-maven-plugin/issues/37)). I've submitted a pull request fixing this, you could grab my fork and build the plugin.

Alternatively, if your plugins don't change often, you could add them manually in the GUI: open the menu Edit -> Preferences, switch to the Plugins tab, install the plugin jar from the local Maven repository. At least on Windows the plugin configuration persists between GUI launches via the registry.